# NOT vs <> Operator in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT id
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT (id = 0)

SELECT id
FROM table1 
WHERE id <> 0
```

In the above 2 queries which one need to be considered in terms of `Performance` and `Coding Standards`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NOT` is a negation, `<>` is a comparison operator, they are both ISO standard.
And have no performance difference for your example.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, `NOT` is used for negation. `<>` means `not equal to`.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance , the two queries almost the same. if you can check the actual execution plan in SQL Server, there is no difference of the two query.

`NOT` is a negation and the other `(<>)` is an operator used for comparison.

how ever if you used `NOT IN` , that is the time if will affect the execution time.

In terms if coding standard, both are being used of different programmers as a standard , but base on my experience, i always encounter the second one.